# How can I generate an STL file for simple triangle in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, 3d, mesh

Can anyone help me to generate an [STL file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)) for simple triangle? From the STL file I want to load a mesh.

Comment: Careful with the tags and terminology - `stl` means something completely different in a C++ context - I've added a link to clarify.

Comment: Oh..sorry Mr Paul.....sorry guys..and thanks for the link Mr paul.